# Bulk loading: Making sure all BulkProcessor jobs are completed (Java Client API)

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make a process that bulk loads data to ES so that

1. There are two indices: index_1, index_2 and an alias that points to index_1 or index_2
2. The data is bulk loaded to index_1 or index_2
3. If all data is loaded without failures, the alias is changed

I'm using the Java Client API.

I would like to be sure that when I add data to BulkProcessor it has completed all jobs before I continue to evaluate if there were any failures. I keep track of failures in BulkProcessor.Listener.afterBulk.

In my current test implementation, when all data is pushed to BulkProcessor, I call BulkProcessor.flush() and then I have added a timeout (just to be sure) before I check if afterBulk has recorded any failures.

**But the question is**: What can I do to make sure the BulkProcessor doesn't have any jobs left and all pushed IndexRequests have been completed?

Comment: did you try to set refresh key as true? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html

Comment: @BehzadDadashpour: I think that options has to do with "when changes made by this request are made visible to search". I'd like to know if the BulkProcessor has any work left.

Comment: in my case, i get count of inserted data after bulk insertion, after this change (refresh = true) i get true value, is your bulk data too big?

Comment: @BehzadDadashpour Ok.. That is a possible solution, I happen to known the count. Also I was considering that I could have a set of all ids to be stored and in afterBulk remove all successful ids from the set -> when the set is empty, all jobs are completed

Comment: But anyway, I was wondering if there is something more specific that could be done. It is a bit strange if there is no support for this, for I think this should be a quite common requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism in Java Client API (v <= 7.0) to check the size of bulk queue. You can keep track of added ids and ids marked ready (afterBulk) yourself.